# How to access values of keys that are objects in js Map

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I am trying to store values in a JavaScript Map using an object as a key. However I am unable to access them using the [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) method provided by Map object. This is what I am trying to do -

```
let map1 = new Map();
map1.set({a: 1}, "valueforobject");
console.log(map1.get({a: 1})); //expected this to print valueforobject but got undefined
```

When I am logging the map itself however I can the that the value has been stored safely. How do I access this using the get method or any other way appropriate here?

Comment: knowing the following may help ... `{a: 1} !== {a: 1}` ... but `var a = {a: 1}; a === a;`

Comment: Bravo thank you got what you wrote, in that case how can I store value using an object key in a Map and safely access it later. Or should I not be using it at all in which case what are my alternatives?

Comment: Oh, I thought that would be obvious if you understood why that comment was relevant ... here it is in a way that's 100% relevant to your code - `var a= {a:1}; map1.set(a, "valueforobject");console.log(map1.get(a));`

Comment: I will actually be constructing the object based on the use case, to fetch the value from the map at a later time. Thats why this would not be useful.

Comment: Ok, so a map with an object as the key isn't the appropriate tool - you'll need to use a different way to make the key, or different object altogether - if you're careful, you could use `JSON.stringify({a:1})` as the key

Comment: I see I think I should open a different question in that case since you have already answered this particular one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Take a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#using_the_map_object).

```
let map1 = new Map();
let keyobj = {a: 1};
map1.set(keyobj, "valueforobject");
console.log(map1.get(keyobj));
```